# Books about Ma'ros of Dam Nidda

Tags: jewish-books, niddah, color

I doubt that there are many but I am would be interested to know if there are any Sefarim written about the different colors of blood which render a women impure which are available to the public.
I once saw a pamphlet a couple of years ago written by a Rabbi in Jerusalem defending the "Tepliker" mesorah and explaining it quite thoroughly. I no longer remember who this Rabbi was though so i know that these seforim do exist.

Comment: This often seems to depend on the rov's eyesight so would be hard to quantify.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When I learned Hilchos Nidda in YU, my Rebbi quoted extensively from a 2 volume set called "תא חזי", available at many seforim stores. [Vol 1](https://zbermanbooks.com/%D7%AA%D7%90-%D7%97%D7%96%D7%99-%D7%94%D7%90%D7%95%D7%A6%D7%A8-%D7%94%D7%92%D7%93%D7%95%D7%9C-%D7%91%D7%A2%D7%A0%D7%99%D7%A0%D7%99-%D7%9E%D7%A8%D7%90%D7%95%D7%AA-%D7%94%D7%93%D7%9E%D7%99%D7%9D-%D7%97%D7%90), [Vol 2](https://zbermanbooks.com/%D7%AA%D7%90-%D7%97%D7%96%D7%99-%D7%94%D7%90%D7%95%D7%A6%D7%A8-%D7%94%D7%92%D7%93%D7%95%D7%9C-%D7%91%D7%A2%D7%A0%D7%99%D7%A0%D7%99-%D7%9E%D7%A8%D7%90%D7%95%D7%AA-%D7%94%D7%93%D7%9E%D7%99%D7%9D-%D7%97%D7%91)

I don't think that they have pictures, but these things can't really be captured in a picture. It's about the halachos.

Comment: https://www.google.com/search?q=niddah+color+chart&source=lmns&rlz=1C1AVUA_enGB781GB921&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwiw75jpl_fxAhWT0YUKHeiZAnEQ_AUoAHoECAEQAA